# Software Foundations '|-' notation shadows Ltac match notation

Tags: coq

[Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/) uses `|-` in a couple of its notations. For example, in [Stlc](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Stlc.html):

```
Reserved Notation "Gamma '|-' t '\in' T" (at level 40).
```

This interferes with the Ltac match construct. For example, this:

```
Ltac test :=
  match goal with
    H: _ |- _  => idtac
  end.
```

works fine outside of Stlc, but once that notation is defined, it fails with:

```
Toplevel input, characters 43-44:
Syntax error: "\in" expected after [constr:operconstr level 200] (in [constr:operconstr]).
```

Is there anything that can be done, other than changing the `Gamma '|-' t '\in' T` notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't anything that can be done here to *really* fix the problem. Coq's extensible parser is very brittle, and conflicts like that can cause certain things to become unparseable.

A workaround is to declare the notation in a module:

```
(* Foo.v *)
Module MyNotation.

Reserved Notation "Gamma '|-' t '\in' T" (at level 40).

(* Include actual notation definition somewhere here *)

End MyNotation.
```

To use the notation, just import the module:

```
(* Bar.v *)
Require Import Foo.

Import MyNotation.

Definition asdf := 4.
```

Then, you can use `Foo` and `Bar` elsewhere without having the notation conflict with ltac code:

```
(* Baz.v *)
Require Import Foo.
Require Import Bar.

Ltac test :=
  match goal with
  | H : _ |- _ => idtac
  end.
```